# sendgrid how to render array item dynamic templates

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

**how to render array item:**

**How to render first 2 array items in 1 column and next 2 in next column**

2 issues:

**1.how to render array item:**

data:

```
companies: ["company1", " company2", "company3", "company 4"]
```

html:

`<li>{{ companies.[1]}}` not working.

**2.How to render first 2 array items in 1 column and next 2 in next column**

```
companies: ["company1", " company2", "company3", "company 4"]
```

flexBox not working for gmail client :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TEST DATA:

```
{"companies": ["company1", " company2", "company3", "company 4"]}
```

HTML:

```
{{companies.[0]}}{{companies.[1]}}
```

Resulting HTML with test data:
`company1 company2`